# Composer Runtime Error with SVN

Tags: svn, composer-php

Background: I am on a Windows 10 machine. SVN and Composer are running locally on my machine.

In my composer.json file I have an SVN reference that reports an error when I try to do `composer update --lock` in cmd line.

The error I get is `[RuntimeException] Package could not be downloaded, 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The problem is that I can also run `svn help` in cmd line and get a list of help topics/can run any other svn commands there. So the path variable is working right. It's setup pointing to the right folder in both environment variables and in my user variables.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "CHANGED_FOR_SECURITY",
  "description": "Module",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "proprietary",
"keywords": [
    "zf2", "mbs"
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "mbs/Zend",
            "version": "1.11.10",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://www.MY_URL_HERE.com",
                "type": "svn",
                "reference": "trunk/MBSWebApp/Zend"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                    "../"
                ]
            },
            "include-path": [
                "../"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.8",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.5",
    "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "1.*",
    "mbs/Zend": "1.11.10",
    "cpliakas/jira": ">=1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "apigen/apigen": "dev-master@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*@dev"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"MbsCore": "src/"}
},
"classmap": [
    "./Module.php"
],
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Also of note. If I substitute svn in the json for a random string of letters it gives me the error `[InvalidArgumentException]
  Unknown downloader type: randomString. Available types: git, svn, fossil, hg, perforce, zip, rar, tar, gzip, xz, phar, file, path.` So I feel as if the json is right, but I cannot figure out where else the issue would be.

Comment: Do you receive any error when you change `"type": "svn"` to `"type": "vcs"` and run composer again?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that composer runs under different account that's missing the entry in %PATH% environment variable. Composer checks for VCS executables in %PATH%, so you should check that it contains the directory with `svn.exe`. Don't forget to check other Composer's config files, too.